# Why is my vertical padding being squelched?

Tags: css

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/legidemike/1/)

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the padding extends over the header above. Why isn't the table cell expanding to accomodate the height?

Code pasted below.

```css
.index-table {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.index-table thead td,
.index-table thead th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #676A6C;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}
.index-table tbody tr td,
.index-table tbody tr th {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  padding: 0;
}
.index-table tbody tr td.btn-group,
.index-table tbody tr th.btn-group {
  padding: 3px 3px 1px 3px;
}
.index-table tbody tr td > span,
.index-table tbody tr th > span,
.index-table tbody tr td > a,
.index-table tbody tr th > a {
  padding: 15px;
}
.index-table tbody tr td > a,
.index-table tbody tr th > a {
  color: #676A6C;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.index-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
.index-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
.index-table tbody tr.clickable-row:hover {
  background-color: #f0f4fc;
}
```

```html
<table class="index-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Vehicle</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><span>No bookings found.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span is an inline-element.
Just adding padding won't change the element.

use display:block; or display:inline-block; to change it so that the padding will work.

```
.index-table tbody tr td > span,
.index-table tbody tr th > span,
.index-table tbody tr td > a,
.index-table tbody tr th > a {
  padding: 15px;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Derp! Don't know why that didn't occur to me. Maybe because the horizontal padding worked, or Developer Tools threw me off. That's an easy fix, thanks for the help!